# qgis2web Plugin Broken?

Tags: qgis, web-mapping, qgis2web

After the qgis2web plugin was upgraded last week the popup window shows all fields in the attribute table when you click on a feature regardless of which ones were selected in the dropdowns when creating the webmap.  Is it just me or is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of qgis2web has changed. If you don't want a field to appear in the popup, set its edit widget to Hidden. The popup field options in qgis2web now control the layout of the fields in the popup. Details are on the help tab of the plugin or the [README](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/blob/master/README.md). Full instructions are in the wiki: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/wiki/fields,-attributes,-and-popups